# Why will spellcheck not work under the "/select" request handler?

Tags: solr

I am trying to install the spellchecking component into my Solr installation.  I have confirmed it works fine, by running the "/spell" request handler which is built into the default config.

But when I try to install this component under the "/select" handler, the system hangs.  Queries stop returning, the system won't ping, etc.

*Any other handler name works fine.*  I can call the handler "/query" or "/gumby" -- it works great and returns results and spell-checking suggestions.  But if I take an otherwise working handler configuration and rename it "/select," the system hangs.

Why would this be?  What is so magical about the "/select" handler name?

(One theory: does spell-checking call the "/select" handler?  If so, then would this set up an infinite loop?  But wouldn't this break search when I comment out "/select"?)

**Update:** It has something to do with "collation."  If I turn that off ("spellcheck.collate=false") then it works fine.  I suspect collation is what runs the alternate spelling searches against the database to get the counts, and thus recursively calls "/select".

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in solr, that the default handler has to have maxCollationTries set to 0 if collation is used.

You can make another request handler the default (e.g.
`<requestHandler name="/select0" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">`) with `<str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">0</str>` or not using collate for that handler, and still use /select with the maxCollationTries set to another value.